# How to get ES6/2015 imports/modules working in browsers?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader, es6-modules

I can't seem to get [ES6/2015 imports](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports) to work. From [this Understanding ECMAScript 6 book](https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read#leanpub-auto-what-are-modules), I understand I need to write my `<script>` tags with a `type` attribute of `modules`:

```
<script type="module" src="module.js"></script>
```

Then I can use `import` within `module.js`. However, it doesn't work on the latest Firefox (v48.0.1) and Chrome (v53.0.2785.89). Nothing gets logged to the console when I put a `console.log` statement in `module.js`.

How can I use ES2015's import mechanism in a browser (natively, not using something like babel/webpack)?

***UPDATE***: Looks like [Microsoft's Edge browser supports modules](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/05/17/es6-modules-and-beyond/#B9Cj0quqrvCxXHTB.97), at least in experimental mode. Why aren't other browsers supporting it yet then, at least in experimental mode?

Comment: ES6 modules are not supported in browsers yet.

Comment: You... can't. Wait for the runtimes to support it and use webpack in the mean time.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import no support yet

Comment: The key thing is that while the syntax for modules has been defined in the ECMAScript 6 spec, the logic for deciding how modules are loaded has not, which is why browsers have not implemented them yet. Babel just uses Node's CommonJS module loading behavior.

Comment: 'How to get X to work'  is **not** the same question as 'Which browsers support X'. Stop marking everything about Javascript as a duplicate of each other please.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Chrome and Safari now [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module) ES6 modules.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The syntax and contract has been defined in the ECMAScript specification, but no implementation exists in any major runtime.

Until some platform provides a built-in `System` object and the associated module loading, you're stuck with Webpack or something similar to polyfill.

While this may seem like a dramatic omission on the browser's part, the feature is easy enough to polyfill.

Comment: Is there a good polyfill library for this?

Comment: I believe both [Webpack 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103641/dynamic-system-import-with-webpack) and [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) support the `System` object and most features on it. They are both much heavier than just a polyfill, unfortunately.

Comment: Actually Webpack shims `System.import` at *transpilation time* i.s.o at *runtime*. So internally in your bundle.js modules are looking each other up using `System.import` (or `import`) but from the outside this won't help you. At runtime you will still not see a `System.import` object that you can interact with.

Comment: As of September 2017, Chrome and Safari now [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module) ES6 modules in the stable version, while Firefox supports them behind a flag.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment the `import` and `export` ES6 features aren't supported natively by any browser (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export for more informations about it).

You need to use a compiler that will convert your code using these keywords, one of the most common and used is [babel](http://babeljs.io/).

Comment: I'm aware of babel, as I mentioned in the question. Strange that it seemed like modern browsers were almost 100% on ES6/2015 (at least according to https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Comment: The ES2015 standard defines the syntax and semantics of importing and exporting variables, but it does not define where modules can actually be loaded from. I believe that's part of an upcoming HTML/DOM standard.