# In Typescript how to do C# Activator.CreateInstance ()

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli, es6-modules

At present my solution is through the import to dynamically generated, there are other ways to not through the import?

[live demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/pBQM9TXfAICrh8dFRMmV?p=preview)

---

abc.ts

```js
export class abc{
  constructor(){
    alert('hello world');
  }
}

export class abc2{
  constructor(){
    alert('hello world2');
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
...
import * as myModule from './abc';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent { 
  
  createAllClass(){
    let allClassName = ['abc','abc2'];
    allClassName.forEach(className => {
      new myModule[className]();
    });
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript file is a module, without referencing module it is impossible to access its exports. You could use `index.ts` and re-export all classes to minimize amount of imports.

You could also play with WebPacks `System.import`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41497903/491265).

Comment: [live demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mf3uEQjjtuq4VUPXpY1h?p=preview) Do you mean that?