# React: Runtime loading components

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a component that pops up at different points in the application.
In the popup component I have several child components grouped by their usage, these are already imported in, *statically*.

I then use a switch statement to render the different groups of components depending on a prop *usage* passed in.

This is working ok, but the switch statement (and imports) is growing.

Is their a way I could pass in the components at runtime and have them render. So that at any one time only one group of components is present/instanced in the popup ? Just trying to do away with the switch statement and the static imports

*pseudo code*

```
<renderPopup children={[ componentA, componentB ]} />

<renderPopup children={[ componentA, componentB, componentC ]} />
```

Is this something that Webpack could do ? But would prefer it to be code rather than config ?

The child components will have static imports etc.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is something called async code splitting in Webpack.

Here is the documentation: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/#require-ensure-

Basically, you can tell Webpack to create a split point at some area, then use cleaver tricks to make those modules load only when required. Using routes make it easy since `react-router` already has dispositions for that, but it's not too hard to do so with a manifest and registry system.

Comment: Thank you for answering, just need to get my head around this now :-) I've upped your answer

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what I should be doing

[Dynamic System.import with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103641/dynamic-system-import-with-webpack)

Webpacks *System.import* seems the answer but if there's another way please post

Comment: Just to let you know, `System.import` is deprecated. They recommend using `import()` now. (https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/#system-import-is-deprecated) I still prefer `require.ensure` since it allows you to name your chunk.

Comment: @gretro You can name chunks in `import()`, it was added in version 2.4.0 https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v2.4.0

Comment: Oh, awesome. I'll take a look at it again. I preferred having a Promise, but this lack of functionality irritated me.